# onResume in android Service

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-service

In my application I have a `Service` that creates some `Thread`s.
When the device goes in sleep mode, the threads are interrupted and destroyed. Assuming that I cannot use my `Activity`'s `onResume()` (because I am using `StandOut` library and `StandOutWindow` extends `Service`), how can I recreate/restart the `Thread`s when I wake up my device?

Would be catching screen on/off `Intent`s a good idea?

Comment: According to your statement, I think it is not only your thread got destroyed during the system suspend, but also that your process is killed in background. If this is the case, you should return START_STICKY in your onStartCommand of your service class. Then after the service auto restarts, re-create your thread again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System suspend should not destroy your thread, it just put your thread suspend. Your thread should not be always running, if it need to finish its job, grasp a weak lock.

You can register a runtime broadcast receiver to watch screen on/off state to handle it. It is a normal approach.

Comment: The thread keeps polling in a while(true) loop. It never ends, maybe that's why it is destroyed while going in sleep. I'll use broadcast to monitor screen power then. Thanks